# How to change Inkscape display language?

Tags: language, macports, inkscape

After installing Inkscape using macports, as described on the [inkscape page](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-0.92.4/mac-os-x/macports/dl/), I had a problem with the UI display language.

Menu items appear in three different languages. Main one - English, and also two different languages, which I usually use.

Question: How to change the display language so the UI is displayed in one language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can find the answer to this problem on the inkscape forum: [inkscape not in english on my mac?](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=13114)

> Please try this: File menu > Inkscape Preferences > Interface > Language (requires restart) > System default (or whatever language).

In my case the language was set to the System default, and this option did not work correctly. Specifying the language explicitly solved the problem.

Comment: It's based on the locale and not the system language; since I use different locale from the system language, Inksape shows up in a different language than what it should be. The reason why there's a mismatch is because I'm using the format of the country I reside in. – Next issue is that there's no preferences under the file menu. What you have to do is go to: second rolldown-menu, last option, and in the popup you select the second item that can be expanded, and the first option on the new screen to the right is the language, set to system by default.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT MENU
NOT
file menu > Inkscape Preferences > Interface > Language (requires restart) > System default (or whatever language).